# how can I output the entire website as "static" files (ie. html, css, img)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a dev site in MVC but wish to render the "pages" and corresponding "assets" (js, css, images, etc) to what one might call a "static site".

In other words, I don't want to deploy to an IIS server that supports MVC. I simply want to build the site in MVC then somehow parse those pages into static html/css/etc files and upload the site to a regular LAMP host.

Is there an easy way to automate this? NuGet package? Binary? MVC extension like maybe a handler add-on that can render out the static site in a single pass?

Are there "plugin" type of tools for this before the site is published to a public url?

Comment: Sounds like a "I want to use a drill to hammer in some nails" kind of problem. The answer is "use a hammer".

Comment: It doesn't sound anything like a hammer/drill problem. It sounds like a static site generator problem. I'm not familiar with .NET implementations for static site generation, but this blog post might point you in a better direction (it lists a bunch of tools at the top and goes into one called Wyam in some depth): https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringWyamANETStaticSiteContentGenerator.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use tools like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to download a complete website as static HTML page with all resources (CSS, Images & javaScripts etc) onto a folder. There are many such free or paid tools available over the internet.